# Loading a solution causes exception at start of Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2015, codelens, activitylog

I recently added some extensions to Visual Studio 2015 Community and since then I experience this error message when I load a solution:

[image]

I tried to run Visual Studio as administrator and disabled/uninstalled the new extensions, but nothing helps or indicates to the problem.

The log shows this error message:

```
  <entry>
    <record>652</record>
    <time>2016/07/23 03:07:44.289</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass22_0.&lt;CreateIndicator&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensDataPointTemplateService.CreateIndicator(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor, String dataPointProviderName, Func`1 viewModelReferenceFactory)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.CreateIndicator(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor, Lazy`2 provider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.IndicatorCollection.UpdateTemplateCollection()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.IndicatorCollection.Connect()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.IndicatorCollection..ctor(CodeLensIndicatorService indicatorService, ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.CreateIndicatorCollection(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensAdornmentViewModelProvider.CreateAdornmentViewModel(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensAdornmentCache.GetOrCreateCacheEntry(ICodeLensTag tag)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensAdornmentCache.GetOrCreateAdornment(ICodeLensTag tag)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTagger.AdornmentHost.TryConnectAdornment()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTagger.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass41_0.&lt;CreateDelayedAdornments&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint[T](Object errorSource, Func`1 call, T valueOnThrow)</description>
  </entry>
```

In the extension manager the typescript extension is grey-ed out:

[image]

Any idea other than reinstalling Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Visual Studio is too old / incompatible.

An upgrade to the latest version [Visual Studio Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) resolves the issue.